# TypeError: GetNamedAccounts is not a function

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

This error:

```
TypeError: GetNamedAccounts is not a function
```

gets printed when i try to deploy my contract with this piece of code:

```
yarn hardhat deploy --network sepolia
```

I've tinkered with dependencies for a few hours and here's what i ended up with (and it's still doesn't work):

```
// hardhat.config.js

require("dotenv").config();

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("hardhat-deploy-ethers");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");

const SEPOLIA = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL; 
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY; 
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.23",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: `${SEPOLIA}`,
            chainId: 11155111,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
        },
        localhost: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
            chainId: 31337,
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
    namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
            default: 4,
            11155111: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
        },
    },
};
```

```
// package.json

{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.10",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.45",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethers": "^6.10.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.19.4",
    "hardhat-deploy-ethers": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Here's the deploy script (i try to use hardhat-deploy plugin as you may have guessed):

```
module.exports = async ({deployments, GetNamedAccounts}) => {
    const { deploy } = deployments;
    const deployer =  (await GetNamedAccounts()).deployer;
    const elections = await deploy('Elections', {
    from: deployer,
    args: [],
    log: true,
    confirmations: 3,
  });

    if ((network.config.chainId == 11155111) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        await verify(elections.address, []);
    };
};
```

I would be extremely thankful if somebody helped me (please)

---

Yes man, it indeed helped, thanks! I was so convinced i spelled it correctly i didn't check it.. I'm getting another error now though:

```
Error: ERROR processing /home/andrii/Documents/Elections/ElectionsBackEnd/deploy/01-deploy-elections.js:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at getFrom (/home/andrii/Documents/Elections/ElectionsBackEnd/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1642:14)
```

I do this:

```
    const { deployer } =  await getNamedAccounts();
    console.log(`Deployer is ${deployer}`);
```

and it prints that '`Deployer is undefined`'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is the starting capital letter, I do: `getNamedAccounts`.

Try to both declare it and call like that and let me know if it solves